# How can I make Windows 10's ssh-add non-persistent?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, windows-10-v1909

I am using Windows 10's (1909) "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" (`net start ssh-agent`). I add keys using `ssh-add.exe`, but I am wondering why these keys are still active immediately after rebooting my machine:

```
C:\> ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:... bersbers (RSA)
```

I have tried using the `-t` parameter to limit at least the time, but then I get a `communication with agent failed` error, while adding the works fine without `-t`:

```
C:\>ssh-add -t 24h bersbers.openssh
Enter passphrase for bersbers.openssh:
Could not add identity "bersbers.openssh": communication with agent failed

C:\>ssh-add bersbers.openssh
Enter passphrase for bersbers.openssh:
Identity added: bersbers.openssh (bersbers)
```

This is the SSH version that I am using:

```
C:\>ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I begin to think this is not possible. Well-hidden in the Win32-OpenSSH wiki, I found this:

> ssh-agent only supports '-l' '-L' 'd' and '-D' options. It ignores '-c' and '-t' options of ssh-add. It persistently and permanently stores the user's private key.

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Various-Considerations

And both limitations are discussed as issues here:

- Persistency of decrypted key: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1487
- Support of `-t` parameter: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1056

Answer (score 0):

You could add

> ssh-add -D

to your "startup" script so that all the keys added to your environment in prior sessions are cleared out and you start with a clean slate every time.

Comment: That might work, I guess. But it does not save you from potential security issues from not rebooting often enough (e.g., using sleep or hibernate instead).

Comment: @bers - OP had specifically said "but I am wondering why these keys are still active immediately after rebooting my machine:", but I guess your point about sleep/hibernate is also a valid concern.

Comment: OP (me, btw :D) asked how make "`ssh-add` non-persistent". You are correct that my first observation of the problem was related to a reboot, but as you see from the end of my question, my intent is to make keys expire after a given time (and not requiring a given action).